# asp.net mvc 6 tag helper injecting script

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, tag-helpers

I am using tag helper to create input field that uses jquery autocomplete function.

```
 public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        output.TagName = "div";
        output.TagMode = TagMode.StartTagAndEndTag;
        output.Content.AppendHtml("<input id='QuickFilter' autocomplete='on' class='form-control' />");
        output.Content.AppendHtml("<script type='text/javascript' src ='../js/autocomplete.js'></script>");
     }
```

autocomplete.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#QuickFilter").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/PhoneChange/Autocomplete",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { Prefix: request.term },
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function (item, i) {
                    return {
                        label: item["clientName"] + " " + item["clientSurname"] + " " + item["clientPhone"],
                        value: item
                    };
                }))
            }
        })
    },
    messages: {
        noResults: "",
        results: function () { }
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#OldPhoneNumber").val(ui.item.value["clientPhone"]);
        $("#AgreementId").val(ui.item.value["id"]);
        $("#QuickFilter").val(ui.item.label);
    }
});
});
```

The problem is that when my tag helper is triggered and html is generated in console I'm getting error

> ReferenceError: $ is not defined

So my autocomplete script can't find jquery.js file, but asp.net automatically added it  and when I inspect the page I can see jquery.js file but somehow my script can't... Can anyone suggest any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the path to the script file you are using on your tag helper is relative. You should use a more specific path, so you can use the helper on any view (see http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/).

```
<script type='text/javascript' src ='../js/autocomplete.js'></script>
```

should be like

```
<script type='text/javascript' src ='~/scripts/jquery/js/autocomplete.js'></script>
```

So any page finds the reference. "~/" means that is the root of the website.

Comment: Would be useful to see if you are referencing jQuery after the helper is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

This may be triggered by the fact that `autocomplete.js` is included before `JQuery`.

The default asp.net mvc razor layout (`Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml`) includes JavaScript files near the end of the document as described in the following pseudo code.

```
<html>
... content omitted ...
<body>
    @Content <!-- Actual content -->
    <script src="Jquery"></script>
    <script src="Site.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is [a brief discussion](https://robertnyman.com/2008/04/23/where-to-include-javascript-files-in-a-document/) on where to include script in a web page.

To solve this you can:

- Move the library scripts inclusion to the head element at the top of the page.
- Schedule autocomplete.js to be included when the document is ready by using [window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload)